# Laravel Eloquent: How to skip empty categories that don't have any topics in them

Tags: laravel, orm, eloquent

I am building a Forum module using Laravel and Eloquent. I have set one to many relationship between ForumCategory and ForumTopic models. Every thing is OK. I can list categories and then topics posted in these categories using the following commands:

```
$categories = ForumCategory::all();
foreach($categories as $category) {
    echo $category->name;
    echo $category->topics()->count();
}
```

The only problem is that I don't want the first command to return the categories that don't have any posts? For now this code is listing empty categories as well those have 0 topics in them.

I want the following command:

```
$categories = ForumCategory::all();
```

To be something like:

```
$categories = ForumCategory::with/having('ForumTopic', '>', 0);
```

or any other command similar to this.

regards

Ahmed Khan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use has or whereHas for more advanced stuff. If your relation in ForumCategory model to ForumTopic is called "topics" its like this.

At least one topic:

```
$categories = ForumCategory::has('topics')->get();
```

3 or more topics:

```
$categories = ForumCategory::has('topics', '>=', 3)->get();
```

Categories with a topic with a subject is foo:

```
$categories = ForumCategory::whereHas('topics', function($q)
{
    $q->where('subject', '=', 'foo');
})->get();
```

Comment: $categories = ForumCategory::has('topics')->get(); This line worked for me. Instead of using ForumTopic (model name) I have used the "topics" the relationship method name that I have created in ForumCategory model to define relationship. Thanks for the clue this really helped me.

Comment: Ah yes, i didn't know the name of your relations because you didn't post your models. I will update my answer to make it more clear.